# Object Literal Property Value Shorthand incompatible with `this`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript it is possible to do:

```
var a = {this: this}
```

but with ES6 property shorthand I get SyntaxError:

```
var b = {this}; // SyntaxError: this is a reserved identifier
```

This is not a real use case but I am just wondering what is the difference between these two. I thought it should do the same (either create a new object or throw an error).

UPDATE:

I run this example in Firefox 42.0. However it works in babel-node (it creates object `{ this: {} }` without error). So what's the correct behavior?

Comment: What environment is this? It works for me in babel-node.

Comment: Same for me, [works fine here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&code=var%20b%20%3D%20%7Bthis%7D%3B%20)

Comment: It seems to be working in babel-node. See my update.

Comment: Does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The grammar for that shorthand property initializer clause stipulates that the single term used must be an *Identifier*. Because `this` is a reserved word, it isn't an identifier, so you get a syntax error.

The relevant part of the spec is [section 12.2.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer).

Comment: For what it's worth I agree that the fact that you *can* use `this` as a property name but the attempt in the OP fails constitutes a language wart, but you kind-of get used to those as a JavaScript programmer.

Comment: I'm confused about this. First, `{ this }` works for me at least in babel-node. Babel compiles it into `{ "this": this };`, which is perfectly legal. I understand that `{ break }` could not work, even through `break` is allowed as a key, because there can be no identifier `break`. But `this` is a kind of special identifier, sorry if I don't have the terminology exactly right. So, is this a language wart, or is Babel allowing it when it shouldn't, or is whatever engine/processor the OP is using not allowing it when it should?