# React Native useContex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react';

export function useAuth() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('Sa');

  return {name, setName};
}
```

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext();
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {useAuth} from './userHook';
import {UserContext} from './userContext';
import Pagesd from './pagesd';

export default function () {
  const {name} = useAuth();
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={name}>
      <Pagesd />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {UserContext} from './userContext';

function Pagesd() {
  const {name} = React.useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
export default Pagesd;
```

I expected the function useAuth to see Sa Pagesd () typed where am I doing wrong

I want to do the case management, but the name comes in the app js, but I cannot access the children.

Comment: please don't link to images. add the code directly in the quetion

Comment: What function “useAuth”?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's more revealing if you look now

Comment: Do you see any errors? What does the component `Pagesd` look like?

Comment: @losif 
sorry i'm new

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry i'm so new i uploaded it again

Comment: @OnurYıldırım no need to apologise. We’re trying to help.

Comment: May you please explain the issue again? What do you mean by “cannot access the children”?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I want to get <UserContext.Provider value = {name}> name with pagesd contex

Comment: Pass in the value in an object instead? `value={{name}}` At the moment it’s being passed in as a value, but the Pagesd component is destructuring it out.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes it worked, what's the difference between this single brace and pair, many many thanks

Comment: Give me 5 min and I’ll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown so far is correct, with one exception.

```
const {name} = React.useContext(UserContext);
```

The value `name` is being destructured from the return of `useContext`. This is fine if the value being given is an object, but I assume it's not.

```
<UserContext.Provider value={name}>
```

If `name` is not an object, but a string, then the destructure will not work, and `name` will be `undefined`.

To solve this you have two options:

1. Do not destructure the `name` value

```
const name = React.useContent(UserContext);
```

2. Pass the provider an object

```
<UserContext.Provider value={{name}}>
```

React uses curly braces `{}` [to denote a JavaScript expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181303/use-of-curly-braces-in-react#44181455), whereas the inner curly braces is an [object literal property value shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467262/object-literal-property-value-shorthand-incompatible-with-this).